# How to call the method that was just called from another method

Tags: ruby, methods, self

I'm trying to run an input validator that would rerun the method where the validator was invoked from if the input was bad. I'm aware (from a similar question) you can use the `.caller` method to find the name, but I'd like to simply call the method that invoked the current method (I don't need to know what it's name/class is.)

I've grossly simplified/altered my code for brevity here.

```
def stack(input)
    if input == "A"
        puts "Good job. Back to continue on the method you were just in."
    else 
        puts "Try again. Back to the beginning of the method you were just in."
        # invoke the method that called 'stack(input)' on this instance
        # to prompt the user again from whatever method they came from.
        # { insert brilliant code here (in this case, it'd call 'overflow') }
    end
end

def overflow
    p "Misc Instructions / Prompt: Type A to continue"
    input = gets.chomp
    stack(input)
    # continuing code
end

overflow
```

Thx as always!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such case, the standard way is to use `catch` and `throw`.

```
def stack(input)
  case input
  when "A"
    puts "Good job. Back to continue on the method you were just in."
    throw :continue
  else 
    puts "Try again. Back to the beginning of the method you were just in."
  end
end

def overflow
  catch(:continue) do loop do
    p "Misc Instructions / Prompt: Type A to continue"
    stack(gets.chomp)
  end end
  # continuing code
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Sets me in the right direction. Any thoughts on why my question was down voted initially?

Comment: Probably it was not too clear what you meant by "call the method that invoked the current method."

Comment: Hmm...It was clear enough for you to answer perfectly. Regardless, thanks for the input - I reworded the question. Thx again!